# Make exceptions more informative

Tags: java, exception, clojure

Is there a way to make Java Exceptions more informative?

For example, take this code from the ClassCastException docs:

```
Object x = new Integer(0);
System.out.println((String)x);
```

Java will give me a ClassCastException with a message like "Can't cast something of type Integer to String". How can I make it say: "Can't cast the Integer **0** to a String" instead?
And if I tried to cast a String "foo" to a Person, to make it say: "Can't cast the String **foo** to a Person"? So with the value of the object I was trying to cast.

Can I somehow replace the standard ClassCastException by the more informative one, **so I don't have to introduce lots of try/catch-blocks? Subclassing is of course an option, but then I would have to introduce lots of try/catch-blocks.**

The reason why I'm asking is actually because of another programming language which compiles to the JVM, Clojure.

In Clojure, beginners often make this mistake:

```
(def my-list ("foo" "bar"))
```

This results into an error message:

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
```

It would be very helpful for beginners to see something like:

```
java.lang.String "foo" cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
```

so they would get the clue that they are trying to use a string a a function here.

It would be nice to be able to inject these new Exceptions, for a learning environment, without actually re-writing the Clojure Compiler. It could be solved at the REPL level by catching these types of exceptions though. Still I'm curious if this is possible with some nifty techniques.

Comment: I don't quite get it: what more information would `Can't cast the Integer 0 to a String` contain than `Can't cast something of type Integer to String` except the value of that integer? Basically the exception tells you everything you need to know: the class of the object, the class you want to cast to, the code line that cast happens in.

Comment: So the only thing that's really different about your message is that you're including the value of what it is trying to cast? I see that's been answered.

Comment: What would that value tell you? How would it help you fix that cast bug?

Comment: The value could give me a clue about the source of the problem.

Comment: @MichielBorkent no, a stack trace can give you a clue.  Value won't.

Comment: You wouldn't have to rewrite it. Just find the spot to insert this code. I bet it's easier than you think it is. Does the compiler generate java code and then compile it? In that case it should be really easy.

Comment: Nice question!  I've run into the same problem many times myself ... it takes a frustratingly long time to figure out what's going on.  I'd like to know if there have already been feature requests for this to the Clojure devel team.

Comment: I guess cast exception are thrown by the VM itself and not by some library, so either wrap such code in your own function or modify the VM to get more info

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem was discussed at the latest Clojure Conj and is generally accepted as something to work on in the compiler. There isn't a lot you can do after the fact to improve the stack traces yet, but rest assured you are not the only one seeking to improve this.

There is a good chance that the compiler will make the parse tree available to the build tools to enable people to create tools that will be able to interpret stack traces and print more meaningful messages, though these things will take time.

Answer (score 4):

Your question doesn't really make sense.  Perhaps give a better example.  The only thing that is remotely similar to what you are trying to do is intercepting exceptions with an Aspect-Oriented Programming framework (e.g. AspectJ).  You can replace one exception with another, but probably won't give you the ability to actually access the object which failed to cast as in your example.

Comment: provided extra info on why I would like to do this

Answer (score 3):

This answer was typed before the question was edited and Clojure was mentioned.

Make a custom static method for casting to string like CastUtil.castString(). In this method you can check the type before attempting the cast and throw an informative exception that includes the value.

To make it easier to use this new method you can also use import static like this:

```
import static myutil.CastUtil.*;
```

Then in your code you can write `castString(someObject)`

Comment: Yep, this actually solves this very local instance of his problem.  Not sure if he wants a more generic solution though.

Comment: This is a nice solution, but it doesn't provide a solution for my problem. Provided some extra info.

Answer (score 2):

You can surround your block of code with a try/catch:

```
Object x = new Integer(0);
try {
  System.out.println((String)x);
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
  throw new ClassCastException("Can't cast the Integer " + x + " to a String");
}
```

Comment: You are not answering his question.  He explicitly says that he doesn't want to catch.

Answer (score 2):

There are two frameworks in Clojure called [clojure.stacktrace](http://richhickey.github.com/clojure/clojure.stacktrace-api.html) and [clj-stacktrace](https://github.com/mmcgrana/clj-stacktrace), they are used for enhancing the messages you see when printing a stack trace. Have a look on the example below.

Here is the normal stacktrace in clojure repl :

```
user=> (java.util.Date. "foo")
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
```

Enhanced stacktrace :

```
user=> (use 'clojure.stacktrace)
nil
user=> (print-stack-trace *e 5)
clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
 at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval (Compiler.java:4658)
    clojure.core/eval (core.clj:2035)
    clojure.main$repl__7403$read_eval_print__7415.invoke (main.clj:183)
    clojure.main$repl__7403.doInvoke (main.clj:200)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:426)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't, unless you use a custom JVM.

When the class cast happens at run time, it is the JVM's responsibility to instantiate a `ClassCastException`, fill in its message and throw it. In HotSpot, the message-constructing part is implemented in C++; see the method `generate_class_cast_message` in [sharedRuntime.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/bsd-port/bsd-port/hotspot/raw-file/9785f6d2dd97/src/share/vm/runtime/sharedRuntime.cpp), line 1479 (this is OpenJDK 6; the code has been slightly reorganized in JDK 7, but the principle remains the same).

Answer (score 1):

Catch it and throw it again with your message.

```
try {

} catch(ClassCastException ex) {
    throw new ClassCastException("Your own message here!");
}
```

Comment: You are not answering his question.  He explicitly says that he doesn't want to catch.

Answer (score 0):

Clojure can be modified to generate code which checks for this condition before it tries to perform the cast and then give you a more informative message.